# Concurrent threads not running concurrently after Archive and Export

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire

When running my OSX application through Xcode, my threads work absolutely fine, however, when I archive the application and `Export as a Mac Application` the app quite clearly jams on the main thread in exactly the place where the concurrent thread was working.

Any ideas?

Some of my code is attached below. The `processData()` function is intense to say the least so it's quite important for it not to bring the entire app to a screeching halt whenever it runs. As I say, it works perfectly when running from Xcode, but doesn't seem to want to play ball when exported. It's rather odd.

```
func reloadTableView() {

    self.noDataLabel.hidden = true;
    self.loadingIndicator.hidden = false;
    self.loadingIndicator.startAnimation(self)

    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("data-processing-queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    NetworkHandler.getLiveMatches(queue, completionHandler: {(request, response, data, error) in
        if response!.statusCode == 200 {
            self.processData()
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.loadingIndicator.hidden = true;
            self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
            self.noDataLabel.hidden = self.dataSource.count > 0
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Xcode 7.3.1, OSX 10.11.3

**EDIT:** Code for getLiveMatches

```
class func getLiveMatches(queue: dispatch_queue_t, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    let parameters = ["ApiKey" : ApiKey]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, BaseURL+"/ApiEndpoint", parameters: parameters).response(queue:queue, completionHandler: { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)

        //print(xml)

        var matches = [Match]()

        if response?.statusCode == 200 {

        // Parse XML into mtch

        matches.append(mtch)
        }

        if matches.count > 0 {
            dataStoreSingleton.matchesArray = matches
        }

        completionHandler(request, response, data, error)

    })
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Queue debugDescriptions,
Concurrent queue:

```
<OS_dispatch_queue: data-processing-queue[0x7fd0da574600] = { xrefcnt = 0x2, refcnt = 0x1, suspend_cnt = 0x0, locked = 0, target = com.apple.root.default-qos[0x7fff78eba100], width = 0x7fff, running = 0x0, barrier = 0 }>
```

Main queue:

```
<OS_dispatch_queue: com.apple.main-thread[0x7fff78eb9a40] = { xrefcnt = 0x80000000, refcnt = 0x80000000, suspend_cnt = 0x0, locked = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x7fff78eba180], width = 0x0, running = 0x0, barrier = 1 , thread = 0x50f }>
```

**EDIT 3:** I can recreate this issue in the Xcode project if I perform `reloadTableView()` multiple times in succession. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: @Cristik yep, runs correctly in Xcode not checked on the app

Comment: @Cristik managed to finally getting around to looking at this again, been busy. I can confirm that the archived application is running purely on Thread 1 and not on an alternative thread. I just can't understand why.

Comment: @Cristik Added to question. I'm beginning to think this is an issue with Alamofire as that manages all the queues

Comment: @Cristik and how would I do this for the archived application? It obviously will show it's working if the project is run through Xcode. As a side note, I just updated the Alamofire submodule.

Comment: @Cristik Okay give me a few

Comment: @Cristik okay, looking at the debugDescriptions of both the main queue and the concurrent queue, the memory references suggest that they are not the same, nor is the queue created nil. Further, by using the queue flags, I confirmed that the block in the request is not running on the main queue, by using `(dispatch_queue_get_label(dispatch_get_main_queue()) == dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL))`. It seems then that the concurrent queue is being placed onto the main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121374/discussion-between-mackey18-and-cristik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here was using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {`.

I don't think GCD liked this, and after some research it seems it's actually bad practice to async the main queue. Instead `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {` should be used. As for the weird behaviour I think it worked when the main thread was empty and the async of the main queue was then put on the main thread - hence everything worked as intended - but when the main thread was busy GCD didn't appreciate the async main queue and plonked all queues onto the main thread.